# 2D plotting in Java

Tags: java, plot, graphics, 2d

Maybe this is only my problem, but I simply can't find this while searching on Google, and it shouldn't be that hard.

I'm looking for a Class/API for 2D plotting.

I need a method in which I give a series of int or double values, and it plots them in a 2-coordinate plane, and draws the plane on a JFrame or JPanel.

Comment: [Github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=java+plotting&type=) is a good place to search.

Comment: I once created a small lib for exactly that: https://github.com/javagl/ViewerFunctions (This is not a recommendation, just a hint. There are certainly "better" solutions for this out there, with **far** more sophisticated functionality. http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/ is probably the most famous one. It's not so trivial to use, but there are plenty of examples out there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method:

```
public void plot(String ints, Graphics g) {
    ints = "put all nums here (e.g. 4,3;9,1;1.1,2)";
    String[] Part1 = ints.split(";");
    String coor1 = Arrays.(Part1[0]);
    String coor2 = Arrays.(Part1[2]);
    g.drawLine(50, 0, 2, heightOfFrame);
    g.drawLine(0, 50, widthOfFrame, 2);
    g.drawLine(45, 40, 10, 2);
    g.drawLine(40, 45, 2, 10);
    int coord1 = Integer.parseInt(coor1) * 10;
    int coord2 = Integer.parseInt(coor2) * 10;
    g.drawOval(coord1-1, coord2-1, 2, 2);
}
```

In theory, this should work - though I haven't tested it - so please tell me about any bugs in this and I'll fix it.
BTW: this only covers 0 and 1 x and y; but it's the general idea to get you started.